# Choosing correct implementation of static member variable of a Java class

Tags: java

I have a java class that looks like this.

```
public class TestImpl implements TestInterface{
private static Fetcher mapFetcher = null;
private Map<String,String> maps = null;
static{
  mapFetcher = new Fetcher();// Fetcher's constructor executes logic to evaluate maps 
  }
  public TestImpl(){
    maps = mapFetcher.getMaps();
}
```

I now have a different class which performs a different logic to calculate maps. I want to decide which logic to use using a flag which  is read from a file

So I thought I could create an interface `MapfetchersInt` and there will be classes `Fetcher1` and `Fetcher2` which implement `MapfetchersInt` and have their own logic to set maps in the class `TestImpl` .

```
Interface MapfetchersInt{} 

Fetcher1 implements MapfetchersInt{}

Fetcher2 implements MapfetchersInt{}
```

Then TestImpl would be

```
public class TestImpl implements TestInterface{
private static MapfetchersInt mapFetcher = null;
private Map<String,String> maps = null;
static{
   if(flag != null && flag.equals("A"))        
         mapFetchersInt = new Fetcher1();
   else
         mapFetchersInt = new Fetcher2();
   }
public TestImpl(){
     maps = mapFetcher.getMaps();
 }
```

I want to know if this is the right way of implementing this. I'm thrown off by mapFetcher in TestImpl class being static. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a command design pattern, one that would allow you to swap out functionality depending on the need. But having said that, please don't do `if (flag == "A")` because that's not how you compare Strings. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will look into the design pattern and update. Will use methods for string comparision

Comment: `if(flag=="A")` should be `if("A".equals(flag))` or `if(flag != null && flag.equals("A")) `

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command I followed this link. It seems like a lot of classes for one flag check in my case.And it is doing the same thing as I am in a more elaborate way. Do you think what I've implemented is correct? I'm worried if doing the check in the static block is somehow wrong. Also I want to know if there is a different pattern I should be using altogether.